# WEB API 2 IQueryable IN Query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, iqueryable

In WEB API 2 how to use IN Query
From SQL string :

```
select * from TABLE where state in (x)
```

To

```
// GET: api/TABLE
public IQueryable<TABLE> GetTABLE(string x)
{
    return db.TABLE.Where(c => c.state.Contains(x));
}
```

Comment: your sql statement does not have a `LIKE`. do you mean `IN`?

Comment: It's my fault. Yes, is IN.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
public IQueryable<TABLE> GetTABLE(string x)
{
    var l = new List<string>() {x};

    return db.TABLE.Where(c => l.Contains(c.state));
}
```